# Different Header on each page

Tags: header-footer, exam

I'm creating MCQ Exam Paper using the `exam` class. 
I'm able to create different Header for first page and remaining pages.

Let us assume there are 5 pages in MCQ Paper such as :

```
Page 1 Header : Paper Details
Page 2 Header : Physics
Page 3 Header : Chemistry 
Page 4 Header : Maths
Page 5 Header : Biology
```

Is it possible to have different header for each page?

Comment: Package `fancyhdr`, for example, but `exam` defines this already. Which header -- left header, central header, right header?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick and dirty method, using `\chead` (the same would work for `\lhead` or `\rhead`) and a `\ifcase ...\fi` conditional.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}


\chead{%
  \ifcase\value{page}
  % empty test for page = 0
  \or Paper Details% page=1
  \or Physics% page = 2
  \or Chemistry% page = 3
  \or Maths% page = 4
  \or Biology% page = 5
  \else
  % Empty chead here!
  \fi
}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blindtext[50]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

[`exam`](http://ctan.org/pkg/exam)s seem to have clear designations between subject matters, and to me is almost synonymous with `\section`al divisions. So, instead of defining fixed per-page headings, define a `\subjectmatter` macro that you can change with every subject matter shift.

```
\documentclass{exam}

\makeatletter
\chead{\@subjectmatter}% Subject matter in centered header
\newcommand{\subjectmatter}[1]{\renewcommand{\@subjectmatter}{#1}\ignorespaces}% Update
\newcommand{\@subjectmatter}{}% Default
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\subjectmatter{Paper Details}
Some details about the paper\ldots

\clearpage

\subjectmatter{Physics}
Questions about physics\ldots

\clearpage

\subjectmatter{Chemistry}
Questions about chemistry\ldots

\clearpage

\subjectmatter{Mathematics}
Questions about mathematics\ldots

\clearpage

\subjectmatter{Biology}
Questions about biology\ldots

\end{document}
```

The convenience with the above approach is that if you have some subject matter spanning multiple pages, there's not real need to adjust the heading for every page.

Answer (score 0):

Also, it's possible to make it by writing different `\chead` on each page.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/187366)

Comment: @AlessandroCuttin why does this not answer the question? It is the manual version of the accepted answer…

Comment: Sorry: that was a predefined comment "from review". The purpose is to encourage DumbSimon to further and better elaborate his answer, so that it is more complete. It is not a rejection of his answer.

Comment: @cgnieder please consider this excerpt from https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx: "Please post rough ideas, suggestions and similar material as comments and reserve answers for actual solutions. You can edit your posts anytime to e.g. add more details to your question or to adjust your answer. Do not use long comment threads for longer or even medium sized discussions. Use chat instead. [...]."
While the approach of DumbSimon is correct, it can be more detailed (by adding a mwe, for example).